# Concurrency of processes for mutex

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, mutex, daemon

I have to write a daemon to decide acces policy for mutexes ( it establishes which process get the mutex if more than one want the same mutex on whatever criteria)

For that I established some codes : L 1 231 (LOCK mtx_id process_pid).
When a process requests a mutex it writes on a shared memory zone some code similar to the one above.
The daemon reads it. (For every mutex I have a queue with processe waiting to get it.) Puts the process pid in queue.
If it is unlocked , pop queue, give mutex.( Write in shared memory id_mutex and process of the pid that got it, for other processes to read and know who has the mutex.

My question is : how do more processe request same mutex ? Creating them at first and selecting the requested process manually does not seem such a good option.

Any help is appreciated.THank you

Comment: A mutex requires a daemon?  Why would you do that?  Can you not just use state data?

Comment: ..besides, 'When a process requests a mutex it writes on a shared memory zone' - that write wou,d require a mutex.

Comment: ...and 'rite in shared memory id_mutex and process of the pid that got it, for other processes to read and know who has the mutex' why would any other process care?

Answer (score 0):

Many OS have a container, a catalog, directory or registry, of OS objects that can be stored by name.  Once stored in the container, they can be looked up by name and a reference token returned.  That token can then be used to access the object.

A synchro object like an inter-process mutex would be a good candidate for storage in the container.  Multiple processes could then look up the mutex by name and use it.

Such cataloged objects are often reference-counted so that they are only destroyed when the last process with a token calls for it to be closed.

BTW - see comments, your design suc.... has issues :(